# Need to scrape the data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am in need to get the celebrity details from https://www.astrotheme.com/celestar/horoscope_celebrity_search_by_filters.php
Input: Time of birth as known only, except the world events in a profession, where I get nearby 22,822 celebrities. I am able to get the first page data, using the urllib2 and bs4

```
import re
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.astrotheme.com/celestar/horoscope_celebrity_search_by_filters.php"
data = "sexe=M|F&categorie[0]=0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12&connue=1&pays=-1&tri=0&x=33&y=13"

fp = urllib2.urlopen(url, data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
from_div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'titreFiche'})

for major in from_div:
    name = re.findall(r'portrait">(.*?)<br/>', str(major))
    link = re.findall(r'<a href="(.*?)"', str(major))
    print name[0], link[0]
```

For the next 230 pages, I am unable to get the data. I used to change the URL as page equal to until end but I can't scrape. Is there any way to get those remaining data from that page?

Comment: who gave me a negative score?  Please tell why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need session cookies, use `requests` to save session easily

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re

url = "https://www.astrotheme.com/celestar/horoscope_celebrity_search_by_filters.php"
searchData = {
  "sexe": "M|F",
  "categorie[0]": "0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12",
  "connue": 1, "pays": -1, "tri": 0, "x": 33, "y": 13
}
session = requests.session()

def doSearch(url, data=None):
  if data:
    fp = session.post(url, data=data).text
  else:
    fp = session.get(url).text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
  from_div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'titreFiche'})

  for major in from_div:
      name = re.findall(r'portrait">(.*?)<br/>', str(major))
      link = re.findall(r'<a href="(.*?)"', str(major))
      print name[0], link[0]

# do Post search in first request
doSearch(url, searchData)

# we have session and we can use Get request for next page
for index in range(2, 4): # get page 2 to 3
  print('getting page: %s' % index)
  pageurl = '%s?page=%s' % (url, index)
  print(pageurl)
  doSearch(pageurl)
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot man. You are awesome. It worked fine for me. Again thanks thanks and thanks

Comment: Why my question got -1 in the score? What is the problem in my question?

Comment: I don't know but I don't do down vote to your question and you're welcome.

Comment: Boss, I am getting Connection error: raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",)) on the line "fp = session.get(url).text" I google it but unable to get that. They ask to change https to http and another one told that add header. I tried both ways but I can't. Is there any other ways there? Actually, you used only 2 pages. I want for until last page. Is it worked fine for you next 200 pages?

Comment: it worked for example `for index in range(200, 204):` it could be server down because your request is too fast try adding sleep between request

Comment: I have already used the sleep and now it worked perfectly. I got the 23000 overall data. Actually, I added the "session.headers.update(headers)" there. Thanks for your patience to answer me. I completed my task and submitted it too. Once again thanks - ewwink